# How to replace number data within a string to a different number?

Tags: php

There is a string variable containing number data , say `$x = "OP/99/DIR";` . The position of the number data may change at any circumstance by user desire by modifying it inside the application , and the slash bar may be changed by any other character ; but the number data is mandatory. How to replace the number data to a different number ? example `OP/99/DIR` is changed to `OP/100/DIR`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string="OP/99/DIR";
$replace_number=100;
$string = preg_replace('!\d+!', $replace_number, $string);

print $string;
```

Output:

```
OP/100/DIR
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the number only occurs once:

`$content = str_replace($originalText, $numberToReplace, $numberToReplaceWith);`

To change the first occurance only:

`$content = str_replace($originalText, $numberToReplace, $numberToReplaceWith, 1);`

Answer (score 2):

Using regex and preg_replace

```
$x="OP/99/DIR";
$new = 100;
$x=preg_replace('/\d+/e','$new',$x);

print $x;
```

Comment: it's quite the same as alexey's answer , so what's difference between using `!` ?

Comment: I used e modifier so that you can execute anything in the second parameter. Regarding !, there is no difference actually. Its just a delimiter. Check http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php .

Answer (score 1):

The most flexible solution is to use preg_replace_callback() so you can do whatever you want with the matches. This matches a single number in the string and then replaces it for the number plus one.

```
root@xxx:~# more test.php
<?php
function callback($matches) {
  //If there's another match, do something, if invalid
  return $matches[0] + 1;
}

$d[] = "OP/9/DIR";
$d[] = "9\$OP\$DIR";
$d[] = "DIR%OP%9";
$d[] = "OP/9321/DIR";
$d[] = "9321\$OP\$DIR";
$d[] = "DIR%OP%9321";

//Change regexp to use the proper separator if needed
$d2 = preg_replace_callback("(\d+)","callback",$d);

print_r($d2);
?>
root@xxx:~# php test.php
Array
(
    [0] => OP/10/DIR
    [1] => 10$OP$DIR
    [2] => DIR%OP%10
    [3] => OP/9322/DIR
    [4] => 9322$OP$DIR
    [5] => DIR%OP%9322
)
```